# Failed to load file in my ruby code

Tags: ruby

I wrote a simple Ruby script, which load a json data file. The project folder structure is like this:

```
projectFolder/
      -- script.rb
      -- data.json
```

The **data.json** looks like this:

```
{
        "company": {
                "name": "ABC",
                "address": "X street"
        }
}
```

The **script.rb** looks like this:

```
require 'json'

data = JSON.load(File.read('data.json'))
name = data['company']['name']
```

When I run my script by command `ruby script.rb`, I get the following error:

```
script.rb:3:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - data.json (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Why my ruby script can't find the **data.json** file to load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `parse` instead `load`, because JSON.parse is to read strings.

```
data = JSON.parse(File.read('data.json'))
```

for me last time working this:

```
  file = File.read('./data.json')
  @data = JSON.parse(file)
```

try read `'./data.json'` instead `'data.json'`

Comment: It works, actually, I have a typo in my file name. Thanks!